# Is it right to make View bind on Instance of Model from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

I am working on new version of application that takes big word file and parse its section to GUI , the current version is written in .Net , WPF framework and MVVM design pattern .

The current architecture which the code is following is like this :

- **View** has a datagrid and the datagrid binds on instance of **Model** in **ViewModel**
- **ViewModel** has an instance of **Model**
- **Model** has List of object of **supporter** class
- **Supporter** class has properties which mapped to columns of datagrid in View

[image: This structure is illustrated in UML for more clarification]

*The implementation:*

[image: View]

[image: ViewModel]

[image: Model]

[image: Supporter]

I suppose to build on the current architecture ; I feel that the current architecture is anti-pattern and it have a tight coupling issue because it is binding on view directly but by using indirect way.

I would like to know If I am right or it is okey to go with this architecture.

---

Comment: Where do you see the tight coupling/binding to view? You are correct that you always bind to view models, not the view, but I don't see that here

Comment: I can not see it too , but I feel it is there ,and this brought up a very naive question which I ask to myself .What the difference between make View bind directly on the Model and make the DataGrid bind on ApplicableDocuments property directly and the bind it using PlanReferencesSection.ApplicableDocuments

Comment: There is no difference, its just a slightly different way of organizing the three properties together. (One *tiny* difference, if your PlanReferencesSection doesn't/can't implement INPC then it would matter if the object gets updated externally. That said, its OK for VM "data" classes to implement INPC)

Comment: from my basic understanding if we are binding on the model directly  that would consider  anti-pattern because  it cancels the use of MVVM which create a layer in the middle to overcome tight coupling as well as you would lose the ability of reusing the  model code . If there is no difference between this and binding on the instance of model from viewmodel that would lead to the same problem which tight copuling . sorry I got confused , so I am trying to make things clear

Comment: It's very common to consider a model object as a DTO and copy values from that into a viewmodel for display and edit. Copy back (often create a new model object) to commit changes. If you bind directly to a model instance you usually then need to "pollute" it by adding inpc and validation functionality. That's considered a bad thing. You also have the option to translate data between viewmodel and model which can be quite useful. The alternative of "wrapping" properties is quite clumsy and usually involves more code. The idea of all this is  to make things easier though.

Comment: While @Andy is, strictly speaking, correct, many times its just a bunch of added work to have a "VM DTO" and a "Model DTO" with no real benefit. In such cases we just let the DTOs float between layers